# Javascript equivalent of pluck and uniq from Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

Hi I am trying to convert my database from Postgres to Mongo and changing from Ruby to Javascript, I am having trouble converting the following query.

```
name_array = RoomRaw.pluck(:name).uniq()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

Also is it possible to do the sum of a row? ie.

```
energy_ac = RoomRaw.where(timestamp: (beginning_of_last_full_hour..end_of_last_full_hour), name: name).last.sum(:energy_ac)
```

Comment: sorry i think i meant ruby => javascript.  yea i've used mongoid for mongo in my rails apps before

Comment: defining re-usables makes it easy:  `function pluck(o){return o[this];} function uniq(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)===b;}  RoomRaw.map(pluck, "name").filter(uniq);`

Comment: okay i think i got confused by the first comment, what i really want to do is to use a mongo query in javascript to get the equivalent of the active record query in ruby. i hope this makes sense...

Comment: It might be helpful if you describe what those Ruby methods you are asking about actually do, for those people who don't know Ruby but do know JavaScript, especially since one of the methods you are asking about isn't even a method from the Ruby core library or standard library, but rather from a pretty specialized third-party library that not even all Rubyists necessarily know. (I don't, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to use a few of these functions without having to re-invent the wheel. While you may be able to write these functions yourself using only JavaScript, I recommend you learn how these functions work overall.

If you're looking to be able to use these types of functions without learning the inner workings, I recommend the [lodash](http://lodash.com) library. It's got exactly what you need.